# Window Phone circular dependency

Tags: windows-phone-7, background-agents

I am working on window phone app.In it i have added another new project that is Schedule Agent that work in background.I have added reference of agent in foreground but when i am adding reference of foreground in agent it gives message about circular dependency.How can I solve this problem?
Actually i want to access local database in both agent and foreground but unable to do that.

Answer (score 0):

You can either:

1. put your shared code in the library that contains the agent and only reference that from the app, or
2. create a new library project where you put your shared code, and reference this new project from both your app and your agent.

As @entropy has pointed out, in either case you need to be aware that any code or  any library referenced from the agent can't contain a call to an API which is [banned by the agent](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh202962%28v=vs.105%29.aspx).

Comment: Exactly,i am trying to put my shared code in class library.To do this i am adding reference of app in class library but when i try to add reference of background agent to class library it gives message that "Unable to add selected reference because it is not supported by background agent",since i have already added reference of agent in app.This is the problem.

Comment: @RiteshGupta there are some APIs that are not supported by background agent, is that the case ?

Comment: @RiteshGupta: I've clarified my answer and added a link to the banned APIs (thanks @entropy)

Answer (score 0):

You can create a new project with the class that you want to share among the main project and schedular task by giving reference of that to both main project and schedular agent..